# Neighborhood shuffle problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, permutations

Suppose there is a street of houses lined up horizontally, numbered $1$ through $N$.

My family lives in house $k$. My neighbor's family gets along with mine. Without loss of generality, let's assume the neighbor's family lives in house $k + 1$.

One morning, every family wakes up at a house of the $N$ houses of the street. (You may assume some sort of uniform selection mechanism.)

I get along with my neighbor's family, so ideally, I would want to live as close to my neighbor's family as possible. After this house shuffle happened, what is the expected distance between my neighbor's family's house and my house?

(Assume if that we live in adjacent houses after the shuffle, that is considered a distance of $1$.)

---

#### My attempt at this problem

Suppose we have houses $H = \{1, \dots, N\}$.

Without loss of generality, suppose the pair consisting of both me and my neighbor's famillies is $(k, k+1)$.

Let $\sigma: H \to H$ be a permutation (bijection).

Then I wish to calculate
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sigma(k)-\sigma(k+1) \right|\right]\text{.}$$

What I am unsure of is **how** to calculate this expectation without brute force calculation (i.e., getting all possible permutations), as well as somehow trying to take into account the uniform distribution of the shuffle (if that's even what it is). The difficulty that I am having a hard time wrapping my head around is that we're not looking at a uniform distribution over $H$; what we're looking at is a uniform distribution conditioned on prior houses already being selected for families.

I found a Wikipedia page and learned that this is a concept known as a [random permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation), but this idea is well beyond my expertise.

Comment: I would assume that the final distance does not depend on the initial one. Do I miss something?

Comment: @user I would agree with that.

Comment: I did not note that the previous places are forbidden. Then there should be some dependence.

Comment: @user Sorry, I shouldn't have included that word in there. I've edited the post.

Comment: Then the expected distance is simply $\frac{n+1}3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assume $|\sigma (k)-\sigma (k+1)|=i,$ in how many ways can you do this? Well you have $2$ options to choose the sign(which one is bigger) and then you can place the smallest one at $1,$ the biggest one at $i+1$ and take them to the right until the biggest one hits $N.$ So, you have $2(N-i)$ ways to do this. Also, you really do not care about what happens on the other houses, so you just pick a random permutation for the $N-2$ choices. You can pick this permutation in $(N-2)!$ ways.
Recall that the expectation is just $$\sum _{i=1}^{N-1}i\cdot P(|\sigma (k)-\sigma (k+1)|=i),$$
but then you now know that this probability, should be
$$\frac{2(N-i)(N-2)!}{N!}.$$ This last is just because we counted the possibilities and they are uniform, so each permutation has $1$ out of total permutations chance to appear, that means $\frac{1}{N!}.$
Can you finish?